# How do I preserve user sessions across subdomains?

Tags: session, subdomain

- I have `defaultCookieDomain` set to `.site.com`
- I am logged into `www.site.com`
- I expected to also be logged into `sub.site.com` (which is pointing to the same web root), but I'm not.

What am I missing?

Comment: Anything in the `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files about you being explicitly logged out for X reason?

Comment: I'll check, but I don't think I'm being "logged out", as I remain logged in on `www.site.com`.

Comment: Nothing in the logs. Just the devMode stuff for the `/admin/` request.

To be clear - to test this I am just going to `/admin/`.
While I am logged in on `www.site.com` but not on `sub.site.com`, I _can_ log into `sub.site.com` (same user), and then be logged in on both.

Comment: Do you happen to be logging in on `www.site.com` over https and testing on `sub.site.com` over http?

Comment: I suspected that and I actually tested it both ways, but got the same result. Also testing logging in at just `site.com` and switching to `www.site.com`, with `.site.com` as `defaultCookieDomain`. Same result.

Comment: On a load balanced setup, maybe?  Just did a test locally with craft.dev and sub.craft.dev and the only thing I did was change `defaultCookieDomain` to `.craft.dev`. Logged into craft.dev and sub.craft.dev CP loaded fine. Can you verify in your browser's inspector that the cookie domain is being set to `.site.com`?

Comment: Weird, I just tried the same thing locally (MAMP) and it still didn't work. You think there might be another config setting that could be interfering? Next I'll try with just a straight vanilla Craft install.

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out, the `appId` setting was the culprit: https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#appId

If using this setting, you probably don't want to set it to something dynamic (as I was, e.g. `md5($url)`).

Comment: Ahh... that's basically the path I was going when I asked about a load balanced setup. They need to share a common appId value in order for sessions to work across multiple servers.

Comment: Yep. Embarrassingly this is what I suspected first, thought I tested it, but apparently I didn't. (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻